# Problem with inner join that returns null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code:

```
SELECT  
    dbo.OpgaveD.Id AS Bilag, 
    dbo.OpgaveD.Dato, 
    dbo.OpgaveD.Tekst, 
    dbo.KoKlDetail.Konto, 
    dbo.OpgaveD.Modkonto, 
    dbo.OpgaveD.Debet, 
    dbo.OpgaveD.Kredit 
FROM dbo.KoKlDetail 
RIGHT JOIN dbo.OpgaveD 
ON dbo.KoKlDetail.Navn like '^[dbo.OpgaveD.Tekst]%' 
inner join Opgaver 
on OpgaveD.OpgaveId = Opgaver.Id 
Where Opgaver.Id = 1 order by Bilag
```

But Konto return "NULL"

The picture below is for "KoKlDetail" table.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vZpe.png)

The picture below is for "OpgaveD" table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdW0X.png)

I am missing column Account must retuner value from KoKlDetail.Konto.

I hope there is someone who can help me with this.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is the intention of this statement  -  like '^[dbo.OpgaveD.Tekst]%'  ? You can rewrite this statement using NOT LINE or using REGEXP_LIKE.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should really start using aliases.

Comment: 1) Wrong title - your `inner join` does not return nulls, `right join` does. 2) Most users here don't open linked images, please provide information in textual form. 3) Offtopic, but unless you think from right to left, use left joins - for example I personally have big problems mentally parsing right joins, esp when they are mixed with lefts.

Answer (score 0):

the null value means that there are no records corresponding to the condition.
Maybe your case is just that there are no records matching the conditions? :)

Comment: No, it's there. Men maybe I need similar words between the 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be much easier to read if you used aliases.  Mixing outer joins in the middle of a `from` clause is really confusing -- and I think it is being turned into an inner join by your other conditions.

I am thinking this might be what you want:

```
select od.Id AS Bilag, od.Dato, od.Tekst, kd.Konto, 
       od.Modkonto, od.Debet, od.Kredit 
from Opgaver o left join
     dbo.OpgaveD od
     on od.OpgaveId = o.Id 
     dbo.KoKlDetail kd left join
     on kd.Navn like '^[dbo.OpgaveD.Tekst]%'
where o.Id = 1
order by Bilag;
```

I doubt your `like` pattern does what you want.  For instance, it is redundant -- you have repeated characters in the character class.

When you need outer joins, the general use-case is:

- Use `inner join`s for table where you require matches.  These go first.
- Follow these with `left join`s for where matches are not needed.
- `right join` is pretty much never needed.

If you are filtering, then filtering on the initial tables (usually the first) goes in the `where` clause.  Filters on the tables on the "other side" of the `left join`s go in the `on` clauses.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is an error about dbo.KoKlDetail: "an expression of non-boolean type specified in a contex where a condition is expected".

Comment: Hi. Your code works like this:select od.Id AS Bilag, od.Dato, od.Tekst, kd.Konto, 
       od.Modkonto, od.Debet, od.Kredit 
from Opgaver o left join
     dbo.OpgaveD od
     on od.OpgaveId = o.Id left join
     dbo.KoKlDetail kd on kd.Navn like od.Tekst
where o.Id = 1
order by Bilag;

Comment: It returns only the exact text, and not if there are more words in the text. example in column Billag No. 2034 is OK, because on in the Text column is  "Overførsel", but Billag No. 2041 returns NULL, because on in the Text column is "Overførsel GIRO 11394582". I am missing it can return value when there are similar words like Billag no 2041. In advance, thank you for your help